# Using Italian Bread for French Toast?

Tags: bread, breakfast

Would this be weird? The bread says it has garlic but that's the only "Italian" ingredient I see.

Comment: Depends, IMHO. As a savoury version of French toast, garlicky bread might be quite interesting, combining garlic and the usual sweet fixings is, well, *for the more culinary adventurous spirits* among us. Me, for example. Don't serve it to your conservative mother-in-law, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

French Toast is just French toast because you are soaking it in egg and pan or griddle frying it.

You can use white sandwich bread, Italian loaf, French baquette, wheat bread what ever. I think we evolved to this in the French toast category.

I don't think the garlic would taste good with the sweet syrup. So yeah Weird. Personal taste though. If its not an overwhelming taste of garlic it should be fine.

Comment: Thank you both. I ended up just going to the store and getting some sourdough and was glad I did.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite French toast is with Italian Bread, but not the kind with garlic--that does not sound good at all.